# Open file with VB.NET application (How does my project know which file is being opened?)

Tags: vb.net, file-io

I am in the process of making a simple image viewer in VB.NET. I want to be able to open an image with my application. How does VB.NET receive the URL of the file that the user is trying to open?

Seems simple but without knowing key terms, my Google searches are returning completely the wrong things!

Comment: if your app is registered to handle a file type, or you have it set up as a SEND TO target, you'll get the filename(s) on the command line. it will parse them for you via Environment.GetCommandLineArgs(). I dunno how a URL plays into this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to inspect the [Environment.CommandLine](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.commandline%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) Property

> This property provides access to the program name and any arguments specified on the command line when the current process was started.
>
> The program name can include path information, but is not required to do so. Use the [GetCommandLineArgs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.getcommandlineargs.aspx) method to retrieve the command-line information parsed and stored in an array of strings.

Comment: Thank you, I think this is what I'm looking for. I'll look into it and mark as answer if appropriate:)